# how to check whether webcam is connected or not in java?

Tags: java, webcam

I have been working on a java project, which requires webcam. I want to check whether webcam is plugged in or not.

Comment: You might want to try and tell a little bit more about what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Using JMF if the webcam is not connect you obtain NoDataSourceException. Take a look on some example like [Web Cam Capture Image](http://www.ivoronline.com/Coding/Languages/JAVA/APIS/JAVA%20-%20JMF%20-%20Web%20Cam%20-%20Capture%20-%20Image.php).

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna have a look into Java Media Framework (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework)